# MAGENTO: cannot find catalog_product table. How does $installer->getTable('catalog/product') work then?

Tags: mysql, database, magento

I looked through the file Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php.

The part of code:

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

/**
 * Create table 'catalog/product'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('catalog/product'))
    ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Entity ID')
```

You can see here catalog_product implementation: $installer->getTable('catalog/product').
But I couldn't find this table in DB.
How does it work then? I always thought that catalog/product = catalog_product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function

```
getTable('catalog/product')
```

can be traced back to

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php
```

checking the `public function getTableName($modelEntity)` you will see that the logic treats also resource table names:

```
<catalog_resource>
            <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource</class>
            <deprecatedNode>catalog_resource_eav_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
            <entities>
                <product>
                    <table>catalog_product_entity</table>
                </product>
```

more resources about this:
[Magento ORM: Entity Attribute Value; Part 1](http://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1) and 
[Magento Setup Resources](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources) from [Alan Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4668)

Answer (score 3):

As is often the case in Magento, configuration is being used. Here's the call stack:

- Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::getTable('catalog/product')

  - Mage_Core_Model_Resource::getTableName('catalog/product');

When a '/' is present in the argument passed to the `core/resource` class's `getTableName` method, the configuration DOM is inspected. First the method will resolve the resourceModel node with the following line:

```
$resourceModel = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->global->models->{$model}->resourceModel;
```

Then, the `core/resource` class calls its `getEntity()` method, with the resourceModel node passed as the argument. This method simply looks under the resolved (resource) model node for the entity declaration (i.e. tablename):

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->global->models->{$model}->entities->{$entity};
```

In the case of catalog/product, the above maps to:

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->global->models->catalog_resource->entities->product;
```

If you look in Mage_Catalog's configuration xml, you'll see this borne out. The reason why it is best to access the tablename via configuration is that it is possible to specify table prefix, and using this method will return the correct name.